# Read field type error from excel file

Tags: c#, linq, excel, dataset

I use this function to read information from xls (2003) file

```
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", path);

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [page1$]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere");

var data = ds.Tables["anyNameHere"].AsEnumerable();

List<client> query = data.Where(x => x.Field<string>(1) != string.Empty)
    .Select(x =>
    new client
    {
        Code = x.Field<string>(1) != null ? x.Field<string>(1) : "None",
        name = x.Field<string>(2),
    }
```

some code in file have Int format like "2100" and other like "G200" but the field(1) was read like double and can't read second type (cast error). I took a look to xls file and the column in standard type even I make it text but I have the same problem.

PS: I used step by step and I found that the data have the field code for the second type NULL.

@GertArnold :

1=> M ; 2801 ; Ronald

2=> M ; 3005 ; Soufian

3=> F ; 2009 ; elizabeth

.

.

121 => M ; G125 ; khaled => le code est lu null

Comment: While I can't help you on the specifics of your problem (not fluent in C#), I can tell you that when Connecting to an Excel file as a DB, the adapter "guesses" the data type based what is in the first few rows of your table. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Pynner : I wrote some ligne in the first of the file with code from second type but In data was NULL !

Comment: Please show the first few lines of the xls in your post.

Comment: The second column is inferred as double for reasons explained by Pynner. Excel format does not make a difference. Any value that is not a double (like "G200") becomes null. That's why OleDb with Excel sucks. Use a third-party component like Gembox or Flexcel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a 4th column with formatting => =TEXTE(B1;"####") and make the same formatting for all the colmne cell and I get the code from this column and it work